# React Native - Firebase Realtime Database and storing arrays

Tags: arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I have an array of strings: `var myFavouriteSites = ["www.fb.com", "www.xe.com", "www.youtu.be"];`

Is there a way I can push this array into the realtime database as one 'field'? All stored in one place? Because I have read that they must be matched with a unique id/key and I am not familiar of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "in one place".  But I can tell you that everything in Realtime Database is essentially key/value pairs, where the values are either strings, numbers, or other objects.  There is no native "array" value type.  Arrays get translated into objects where the keys are array indices.  So if you assign an array at `/location`:

```
["www.fb.com", "www.xe.com", "www.youtu.be"]
```

You'll get a database structure that looks like this:

```
/location
    0: "www.fb.com"
    1: "www.xe.com"
    2: "www.youtu.be"
```

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. But how is the manipulation of the data done? Say if I have the value "www.fb.com" is there a way to get its key (which in out case is 0) and delete the key-value pair from the database? And if it is possible to delete the data what will happen to the remaining keys below it? Will they change their order to: 0: "www.xe.com" 1: "www.youtu.be" ?

Comment: It will behave just like any key/value pair.  The array will then have no 0 element.  It's generally not advisable to store mutable arrays in Realtime Database like this.  Instead, they often push() data at a location along with whatever key is used for sorting the items, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question. If I decide that I would like to push strings with some sort of unique id of random strings or numbers. Is there a way to extract all the values from /location with one single call without actually knowing the keys because they are unique randomly generated ones?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.  Could you format a new question with more details that helps folks visualize and understand what you intend to accomplish?